# What is the meaning of "someone else" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sentence:

> It is a [masked ball](https://www.google.com/search?q=Masked%20Ball&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA39q235fUAhWpx4MKHT0OBp8Q_AUICigB&biw=1440&bih=794). We all go as **someone else**.

Context: Robert & Virginia going to Masked Ball, Above words said by Robert to Virginia before visiting it.

Sentence belongs to "Entrapment (1999)" movie.

Comment: As somebody different from ourselves; resembling someone or something else.

Comment: you mean by changing the **names** of person?

Comment: This too. They can change many things... see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**someone else**" means *"as somebody different from ourselves; resembling someone or something else."*

- "**someone**" is a pronoun that means *"an unknown or unspecified person"*
- "**else**" is an adverb that means *"different, instead"*

When you go to a masked ball you change your identity, you behave differently, your manners are different, you may even cloak your own voice if you can and your gait too if you are able to, you can change your appearance and apply makeup.

A **Masked ball** is an event which people attend wearing masks to hide their true identity.

Comment: I would also add/emphasise changing appearance to the list

Comment: @SteveES Thanks. By saying "*change your identity*" I referred to whatever change is possible. Maybe someone does a plastic surgery for that event.